# How to make landscape rotate only one selected page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to rotate only one selected page others all to be portrait. is it possible?
I only want to rotate this page

```
class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
final List<Posts> bikesToCompare;

Cart(this.bikesToCompare);

@override
_CartState createState() => _CartState(this.bikesToCompare);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
 @override
 _CartState(this.bikesToCompare);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import the services package:

`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

This will give you access to `the SystemChrome` class and can be used to control device orientation.

In your Cart Widget initState, put this code:

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
}
```

In your Cart Widget dispose state, put this code:

```
@override
dispose(){
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  super.dispose();
}
```

I hope this helps